# Get Actor Component Reference in C++ Class

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have made two ActorComponet Scripts in Unreal Engine and attached them to my Player Actor. I wish to include a reference for ComponentA in ComponentB. What is the pattern to do this in Unreal using C++? I am new to Unreal Engine coming from Unity and am trying to understand the pattern.

In Unity C# I could just get a component attached to the same parent using something like this:

```
ComponentA componentA = GetComponent<ComponentA> ();
```

Where ComponentA is the other component script I want a reference to in ComponentB. Both are attached to the same parent. I assume there is something similar in Unreal Engine but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: It depends, id suggest creating them both as default sub objects on their owning actor, and caching pointers to them on that actor. If that's not possible then you could do something like `AActor* Owner = GetOwner(); if (Owner != nullptr) Owner->FindComponentByClass<ComponentA>();` however, find component is an expensive call, that's not to say don't use it, but try and keep calls to it low.

Comment: That does sound expensive because I'd looking through all the components. There must be a cheaper way to have references between two C++ classes attached to an actor? Specifically I have an input class, a physics class and a state class and I need to be able to access their values and functions between classes. I must be missing something... how could I possible write a workable game without being able to reference different class instances in other classes.